# Upload to Dropbox not working .NET SDK

Tags: c#, dropbox

I have the following function that uploads files to Drobox and returns shared links to these files.

```
private async Task<string> Upload(DropboxClient dbx, string localPath, string remotePath)
    {
        const int ChunkSize = 4096 * 1024;
        using (var fileStream = File.Open(localPath, FileMode.Open))
        {
            if (fileStream.Length <= ChunkSize)
            {
                WriteMode mode = new WriteMode();

                FileMetadata fileMetadata = await dbx.Files.UploadAsync(remotePath, body: fileStream, mode: mode.AsAdd, autorename: true);
                //set the expiry date
                var existingDoc = await dbx.Files.GetMetadataAsync(remotePath);
                if (existingDoc.IsFile)
                {
                    var sharedLink = dbx.Sharing.ListSharedLinksAsync(remotePath);
                    var settings = new ListSharedLinksArg(remotePath);
                    ListSharedLinksResult listSharedLinksResult = await dbx.Sharing.ListSharedLinksAsync(remotePath);
                    if (listSharedLinksResult.Links.Count > 0)
                    {
                        return listSharedLinksResult.Links[0].Url;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        var settings2 = new SharedLinkSettings(expires: DateTime.Today.AddDays(7));
                        SharedLinkMetadata sharedLinkMetadata = await dbx.Sharing.CreateSharedLinkWithSettingsAsync(remotePath, settings2);
                        return sharedLinkMetadata.Url;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    var settings = new SharedLinkSettings(expires: DateTime.Today.AddDays(7));
                    SharedLinkMetadata sharedLinkMetadata = await dbx.Sharing.CreateSharedLinkWithSettingsAsync(fileMetadata.PathLower, settings);
                    return sharedLinkMetadata.Url;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                await this.ChunkUpload(dbx, remotePath, fileStream, ChunkSize);
            }
            return "error";
        }
    }
```

But it's not working properly, when it gets to the `ListSharedLinksAsync` function, it stops working witout throwing any error.

I notices that the files that I try to upload are not accessible after it crashes, I get a "used by another proccess error"...

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Aren't you missing an await on this row?
```var sharedLink = dbx.Sharing.ListSharedLinksAsync(remotePath);```

Comment: Which framework version are you using?

Comment: @JOSEFtw good point, I'll try that.

Comment: @dadde- VS 2013

Comment: @JOSEFtw that solved my issue, thank you! I would be happy to mark it as the correct answer, please write it as an answer and i'll do so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are missing an await on this row, thus causing a deadlock?

`var sharedLink = dbx.Sharing.ListSharedLinksAsync(remotePath);`

Should be

`var sharedLink = await dbx.Sharing.ListSharedLinksAsync(remotePath);`